# Subtraction count down to zero game pattern with recursion in c++

Tags: c++, algorithm, recursion

Using recursion I have to make an AI for a game where computer will choose from 4 , 3 or 1 and subtract it from a given number between 1 to 99 inclusive. This game will be played between the AI and a human. However, AI cannot pick any random number from 4,3 or 1. It must always pick values which will help it win the game. Also, when the number is something like 2 , AI or human cannot pick 4 or 3 as it is bigger than 2 so they have to pick 1. Also assume that the AI is player 2 and human is always player 1.

For example : If the starting number is n = 7, then player 1 picks 1 and n = 6 , then computer picks 4 and new n = 2. Player 1 will choose 1 and n = 1. Then AI will choose 1 and n = 0. Hence AI won the game.

What I have thought about this problem so far:

I know different numbers until 6 which should be chosen by AI (from 4, 3 or 1) to win the game.

> For example: When  n =1, choose 1 
>   n = 2, choose 1 ;
>   n = 3, choose 3 ;
>   n =4, choose 4 ;
>   n = 5, choose 3 ;
>   n = 6, choose 4 ;

But I am unable to find a general algorithm which can be applied to all numbers from 1 to 99 to win the game. 
I want to know and understand how to get  a general recursive equation and recursive algorithm like the one in Fibonacci series for a function recursion :

> Fibonacci(n - 1) + Fibonacci(n - 2)

to choose number between 4 3 or 1 by AI to win the game.

I am not experienced at recursion so please try to explain algorithm in detail.

Comment: [Game theory time](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~anupamg/251-notes/games.pdf)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume the player who can not make a move loses the game.
You don't seem to mention it anywhere, but that's the way it looks.

---

First, note that each number is either a winning position or a losing position for the player to take the turn, regardless of which player it is.
For example, number 7 is a losing position: if the current player picks 1, the other one responds with 4; if 3 or 4, with 4 or 3, respectively.

A recursive relation would be as follows:

```
win(x) = not win(x-1) or not win(x-3) or not win(x-4)
```

Indeed, if there is a move which leads to a losing position, we can win by picking that move. If not, our opponent will win, assuming they play perfectly from that point on.

Now, instead of *implementing* the recursion, use it to compute the win-or-loss state of each number from bottom to top, and store it in an array, like this:

```
win[0] := false
win[1] := true
win[2] := false
win[3] := true
for x := 4, 5, ..., 99:
    win[x] := not win[x-1] or not win[x-3] or not win[x-4]
```

This way, you make just 100 simple calculations, instead of traversing the huge recursive tree of all possible games starting with the number 99.

Now, with this `win` array calculated, how to make a move from the number `x`?
If `win[x] = false`, either move will do: we lose anyway if our opponent plays perfectly.
If `win[x] = true`, find which of the `win[x-1]`, `win[x-3]`, and `win[x-4]` exists (beware of underflow!) and is false, and make that move.

---

Lastly, observe that [the computed array](https://ideone.com/nV3wmx) looks like this:

```
[0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1]
```

Clearly, there is a period of 7.
Thus, for this exact game, a custom strategy can be formulated using no array at all, by just looking at the remainder of our number modulo 7.
In fact, you almost did it in the question, just prepend the "remainder modulo 7 is..." to it, and add something about zero:

> For example: When n =1, choose 1 n = 2, choose 1 ; n = 3, choose 3 ; n =4, choose 4 ; n = 5, choose 3 ; n = 6, choose 4 ;

Answer (score 0):

Here is my code for your problem it may help you

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
typedef long long ll;
using namespace std;

int main(){

    //init nimbers
    int arr[100];
    fill(arr,arr+100,-1);

    arr[0]=0;
    queue<int> q;
    q.push(0);
    while(q.size()>0){
        int u=q.front();
        q.pop();
        if (u+1<100 && arr[u+1]!=1)
        {
            arr[u+1]=(arr[u]+1)%2;
            q.push(u+1);
        }
        if (u+3<100 && arr[u+3]!=1)
        {
            arr[u+3]=(arr[u]+1)%2;
            q.push(u+3);
        }
        if (u+4<100 && arr[u+4]!=1)
        {
            arr[u+4]=(arr[u]+1)%2;
            q.push(u+4);
        }
    }
    int n=7;
    cout<<"Welcome to the Game\n";
    cout<<"You are player 1\n AI is player 2\n";
    int play=0;
    while(n>0){
        if (play%2==0)
        {
            int step=-1;
            cout<<"Enter your move?";
            cin>>step;
            n-=step;
            cout<<"Now n="<<n<<endl;
        }
        else{
            int step=1;
            if(n-1>=0 && arr[n-1]==0) step=1;
            if(n-3>=0 && arr[n-3]==0) step=3;
            if(n-4>=0 && arr[n-4]==0) step=4;
            n-=step;
            cout<<"AI played "<<step<<" move\n";
            cout<<"Now n="<<n<<endl;
        }

        play=(play+1)%2;
    }
    if (play)
    {
        cout<<"You won";
    }
    else cout<<"AI won";
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Code-only answers are generally discouraged. Try explaining or describing what should be done and why, instead of just doing it.

Comment: The code is not self-explanatory, and outright confusing. For example, it claims to compute [nimbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nimber), but instead stores only win/loss information. Which would be fine if not for the wrong comment.